# how to add a value to a dictionary when the value is a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to build a dictionary, such that for each key the value is a list of lists.
There is a loop in my code thats runs on some list of keys, and if the key not in the dictionary, i add the key to the the dictionary with some value.
I get into truble when the key is in the dictionary- i cannot add to it another list.

here is example for what i tried:

```
dict={}

dict[x]=[[f,g],[y,e,j]...]
# i tried this:
dict[x]+= [l,k,n]

dict[x].append([l,k,n])

#i expected this:

dict[x] = [[f,g],[y,e,j], ... ,[l,k,n]]
```

Comment: Doesn't the `append()` version do exactly what you want?

Comment: Side note: `dict` is not an ideal name you should choose for a variable. You will run into problems at a later point. It's a [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict).

Comment: That wouldn't prevent the `append()` version here from doing what OP wants.

Comment: So what *did* `dict[x].append([l,k,n])` do, if not what you expected?

Comment: Acutly it works now, i don't know what happened before, probably typo. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```py
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
d = {}
d['ab'] = [a, b]
d['ab'].append([7,8,9])
```

Note that `d['ab'] += [0,0,0]` (as an example) does an `extend` rather than a `append`. If you want to use `+=` then you should wrap the value in a list. e.g.:

```
d['ab'] += [[0,0,0]]
```